# Floating text overlay on image hover

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

What I'm trying to do: When a user hovers over any image on a specific page, a floating box element appears, displaying the Image's title (the html title="" tag). As the user moves their cursor across the image, the box element moves along with it.

(Example: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Glass_Bottle - If you looking under the "crafting" section, hovering over certain images displays a box with it's title - Sorry, this was the only example that I could find).

Is it possible to achieve this result utilising raw HTML, or does this require css or an addition such as Javascript/Jquery?

Sorry if I haven't been clear enough - if you require certain information, please let me know!

Thanks in advance, and I hope everyone has a Happy New Year! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Hello Paulie. Thank you, but I'm not new. I understand this - I have just tried something out, and will post my code, and talk through what I tried to do, the expected outcome and the actual outcome. I hope that my edit will overturn the downvote :/ Thanks for the heads up though, and happy new year.

Comment: This can't be done without JS...CSS has no method to follow cursor position.

Comment: If you read my question, I was simply asking if it was possible to achieve this result using HTML, or if another tool was required. Sorry if I was unclear, should've placed my question at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed. I understand that now, the other answers below stated that - but thanks for you reply, I appreciate it Paulie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need javascript.  I don't think your going to get everything you want in HTML5.  You want to use the mouseover event to show the image next to the cursor which means you'll have to float a div next to it.  The moving part won't be a problem because you'll probably just reshow it for every mouse over which will get fired every time they move the cursor I think.  Here are the problems you must solve.  Figure out one at a time.

```
1) How to float a div at a higher z index with the title in it.
2) How to know the coordinates of your curser
3) Move the div to your cursor coordinates with an offset
4) How to hide the div
```

Comment: Hey javaMoca - thanks for breaking down the problem into those set of steps. This is all relatively new to me, so do you think you'd be able to provide me with a particular set of resources? I'm researching each step at the moment - I'll keep you updated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used this a few months ago and helped me a lot with the very same problem:

http://notlaura.com/show-title-hovering-image/

Hope it helps you as well,

Andrew

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, Andrew - looks great! 

However, using that, the title appears within the image. Is there a way to break out of that and get the title in a separate floating box outside the image?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fb9wy32c/1/ This might not be the best solution for you, but this way you can easily position the title anywhere - although it will not depend on the cursor position.

Comment: That looks great so far, thanks again for the reply Andrew! Just one last thing: How would I get the bottom left corner of that floating box of text to "attach" itself to the tip of the user's cursor as they move across the image?

Comment: Well I tried and tried and tried but cannot make it work with only css+html. Javascript will be needed so that you can get the position of the cursor and display a floating box in front of everything based on the coordinates of the cursor position. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is some workaround or different approach here.

Comment: Hey Andrew - thanks a lot for trying. I'm basically trying to achieve what you created, but with the text essentially "following" the cursor. I think I'll have to try using Javascript to achieve that effect, as you've said. Thanks again for your input though, I appreciate it :)